# toggle tr works only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use this js:

```
var RowT = 1;

function toggleRowT() {
    if (RowT == 0) {
        window.document.getElementById('t1').style="display:table-row;";
        window.document.getElementById('t2').style="display:table-row;";
        window.document.getElementById('t3').style="display:table-row;";
        window.document.getElementById('letter_t').style="opacity:1;";
        RowT = 1;
    } else if (RowT == 1) {
        window.document.getElementById('t2').style="display:none;";
        window.document.getElementById('t3').style="display:none;";
        window.document.getElementById('t1').style="display:none;";
        window.document.getElementById('letter_t').style="opacity:0.2;";
        RowT = 0;
    }
}

var RowD = 1;

function toggleRowD() {
    if (RowD == 0) {
        window.document.getElementById('d1').style="display:table-row;";
        window.document.getElementById('d2').style="display:table-row;";
        window.document.getElementById('d3').style="display:table-row;";
        window.document.getElementById('d4').style="display:table-row;";
        window.document.getElementById('letter_d').style="opacity:1;";
        RowD = 1;
    } else if (RowD == 1) {
        window.document.getElementById('d1').style="display:none;";
        window.document.getElementById('d2').style="display:none;";
        window.document.getElementById('d3').style="display:none;";
        window.document.getElementById('d4').style="display:none;";
        window.document.getElementById('letter_d').style="opacity:0.2;";
        RowD = 0;
    }
}
```

in this file: http://flamencopeko.net/bpm_calc.js

for this page: http://flamencopeko.net/bpm_calc.php

The above code pasted in http://www.jslint.com produces too many errors for them to list. But it's all strange stuff like missing white-space, use === instead of ==, etc.

This is the html for the two buttons that will not work in other browsers:

```
<a href="javascript:toggleRowT();"><img src="/ico/letter_t.gif" class="ico" alt="X" title="toggle triplets" id="letter_t">triplets</a>

<a href="javascript:toggleRowD();"><img src="/ico/letter_d.gif" class="ico" alt="X" title="toggle dotted" id="letter_d">dotted</a>
```

This is the css: http://flamencopeko.net/flame_style.css

Anyone spot the problem(s)?

Comment: you are using `php` :P

Comment: I believe you. I'm a strange person. ;) Good one. Funny that Firefox could interpret that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `style` property on elements is not a string, it's an object. If you want to set the `display` property of that style object, you do that like this:

```
window.document.getElementById('d1').style.display = "none";
// Note display is a property of style ---^               ^
// And there's no ; at the end of the value -------------/
```

(And similarly when setting `opacity`.)

If it works in Firefox, Firefox must have special handling when you assign a string to the property.

---

And I just can't resist a minimal rewrite:

```
function toggleRow(type) {
    var elm, n;
    var display, opacity;

    // Loop through the rows
    for (n = 1; n <= 3; ++n) {
        // Get this row
        elm = document.getElementById(type + n); // t1/d1, t2/d2, t3/d3

        // If it's the first, figure out the values to use
        if (n === 1) {
            if (elm.style.display === "none") {
                display = "table-row";
                opacity = "1";
            }
            else {
                display = "none";
                opacity = "0.2";
            }
        }

        // Set the display
        elm.style.display = display;
    }

    // And the opacity
    document.getElementById("letter_" + type).style.opacity = opacity;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:toggleRow('t');"><img src="/ico/letter_t.gif" class="ico" alt="X" title="toggle triplets" id="letter_t">triplets</a>

<a href="javascript:toggleRow('d');"><img src="/ico/letter_d.gif" class="ico" alt="X" title="toggle dotted" id="letter_d">dotted</a>
```

With more context, I bet we could get rid of the `id`s entirely and make the code shorter.

Comment: Indeed. Super thanks! Works perfect in all browsers now.

Comment: Looking into your rewrite now. So cool of you to do that. Highly appreciated.

Comment: Since there are four dotted I tried to change `n <= 3;` to `n <= 4;`. This caused the D button to not become transparent. I plan to add a few more rows. And I'm uncertain if the number of Ds and Ts will be equal. I understand most of your code, and I'm fairly sure I agree it's the direction to go in. elm is short for element and n is short for number, yes?

Comment: @OleSørensen: If the number may vary, add this after the `elm = ...` line: `if (!elm) { break; }`.

Comment: Excellent. Using your code now. http://flamencopeko.net/bpm_calc.php Thanks a bunch again.

Comment: Here's updated source: http://flamencopeko.net/bpm_calc.txt. Is that what you meant by more context?

Comment: Just discovered the <colgroup> tag. Trying to use that to toggle columns. Works for stuff like background color, but not hiding.